# What does mean /*! some url or text */ in css

Tags: css, comments

I know in CSS we use `/* */` for comment text . But I see in some CSS use `/*! some url or text */`.
What's different between `/* text */` and `/*! text */` ?

Comment: The difference is that in second case comment starts with `!`.

Comment: @dfsq simply right and so wrong.

Comment: @lin Well it depends on the tool used for minification. From spec perspective `!` doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @dfsq Well, it allways depends on the tool you are using. Your comment does not help the user. Stackoverflow is for helping users.

Comment: @lin "Stackoverflow is for helping users.". Haha, sure :D but I don't think so. Cheers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The exclamation mark is to keep an comment important . This comment will not be deleted while compressing. This is important e.g. for keep a licence in a CSS file after compressing. [Uglify](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS/) or [YUICompressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/) will keep that comment after compressing.

```
/*! important comment will not be deleted while compressing */
```