# Exclamation mark in a css property comment results in it being recognized as active

Tags: css

I have a following line in a css file of a React library:

`/*!visibility:hidden*/`

Both Firefox and Chromium do not treat this line as a comment. Property is being applied as though it is not commented. I am not aware of this syntax and cannot find the relevant info online for some reason. What is the purpose of the exclamation mark in this context?

Thanks

Comment: The comment itself is okay and shouldn't be applied. Most probably you have another similar CSS rule which overrides this one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does mean /\*! some url or text \*/ in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42132074/what-does-mean-some-url-or-text-in-css)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The purpose of starting an initial comment with /\*! in javascript and css files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248363/the-purpose-of-starting-an-initial-comment-with-in-javascript-and-css-files)

Comment: That does not explain why properties are actually active in the browser. There are 4 of them with such comment and all of them are active, I am sure those are coming from comments because class name is the same and order or properties is the same as in the css file.